# How to enable Bash in Windows 10?

Tags: bash, windows-10

Although it may seem to be duplicate to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/278185/can-windows-use-a-linux-shell-instead-of-cmd), the fact is, that [Microsoft recently announced that bash will be running directly from windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/)

Obviously I am preferring that solution before installig cygwin.

The problem is, that blog post kinda states that it is already possible, yet I could not find a way to enable this in my windows installation.

What should I do in order to run bash directly as stated in linked microsoft blog post?

Comment: There are 3rd party bashes available now that you can install.  The Windows update that contains the sanctioned by Microsoft bash hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @Tyson reading the blog post made me believe that it already is available, so I wated to try it before installing cygwin or going dualboot

Comment: From you link... "....which will first become available in Windows 10 “Insiders” builds after the Build conference..."

Comment: the blog seems to indicate on a supported version. just runnimg the command would autoinstall it. Give it a shot

Comment: That's not really running "directly from windows," the article title is even "*Run Bash **on Ubuntu** on Windows*". It sounds a lot like it could be a command line only VM. Anyone know for sure? For now, to run it "directly" you could just run full Ubuntu in a full VM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing the Windows Anniversary Update, search for "Developer Mode":

[image]

Select "Developer Mode":

[image]

Accept the dialog:

[image]

Then search for "Windows Features":

[image]

Select "Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)":

[image]

It will then ask you to reboot:

[image]

Reboot, then run `cmd.exe`, then type `bash`. Accept the license. It will download and install:

[image]

This took about 5 minutes to complete on my machine. You'll have to select a username and password too.

Answer (score 5):

As the blog says: "will first become available in Windows 10 “Insiders” builds after the Build conference".

The Build conference doesn't end until tomorrow (Apr. 1, 2016), so it's not out yet.

Once it's out: "Developers will be able to download the Bash shell from the Windows Store."

[Source](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/windows-10-anniversary-sdk-is-bringing-exciting-opportunities-to-developers/)

Comment: Too impatient :)

Comment: It's a great move for Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

The Bash is available since [Build 14316](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/)

[image]

> **Run native Bash on Ubuntu on Windows**: In this build, you can natively run Bash in Windows as announced last week at Build 2016. To
>   do this, you first need to **turn on Developer Mode** via **Settings >
>   Update & security > For developers**.
>
> [image]
>
> Then search for “`Windows Features`”
>   and choose “`Turn Windows features on or off`” and enable **Windows
>   Subsystem for Linux (Beta)**. 
>   [image]
>   To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt
>   and type “bash”.

Microsoft explained all steps in detail [in this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/).

Comment: I do not have the subsystem option. build 14316 and dev mode on. strange...

Comment: @JPHellemons maybe you use the 32Bit Windows 10 Preview. The Linux System seams to only part of the 64Bit Windows.

Comment: Running on Lenovo Miix 2 8inch. it is a 32bit version of win10 indeed, has x64 cpu it seems. Do you know if it will be available for 32bit too?

Comment: @JPHellemons I have no idea. Ask this Microsoft in their forums and send Feedback via the Feedback app