# How do I install Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10, shell

I'd like to install the [Ubuntu Bash](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) on my Windows 10 machine.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you on the Developers Preview build 14311 or newer of Windows 10? (not available to general public, yet)? Or have you installed Ubuntu for Windows 10 from the Windows store (again, not yet available)? No to both, then you can't use bash yet.

Comment: Install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1059767/how-to-enable-bash-in-windows-10?

Answer (score 6):

First off you have to make sure that you're on Build 14311 or higher of the developer preview, which is available to the general public.  From there, follow these steps:

1. In `Settings --> Update & Security --> For Developers`, enable `Developer Mode`

   [image: Developer Mode Enable]

   You'll get a warning about developer mode, select `Yes`

   [image: Developer Mode Warning]
2. Search for "Windows Features" in the Settings Search (Top Right Corner) and select `Turn Windows features on or off`
3. Navigate to and then enable (check mark) the `Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)

   [image: Windows Features]
4. After installation, you'll be required to restart the computer.  This is a pretty large install and may take some time.
5. Finally, open a `cmd` window and execute the command `bash`.  You'll be required to accept the terms and service.  Ubuntu will then be download (~1 Gb in size) and then install.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Great answer, just a question on Step 5 I get this error message `Downloading form the Windows Store... 0%Error: 0x800c0008`.  It happens almost instantly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @tyelford looks like an [account issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/microsoft-account-login-error-0x800c0008-windows/292f601d-f958-4210-b6d8-0c3b0254baf8?auth=1) and not an installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Opens a cmd.exe console

Means you need to go to *Start* -> *Run...* and type `cmd`, or by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

The [`cmd.exe`/`cmd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) stands for *Command Prompt* and it's the command-line interpreter on Windows (similar to Bash).

It's better if you install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) which will provide Bash shell out-of-box. After installation you'll have shortcut created on your Desktop, so you won't have to run `cmd` anymore in order to run Bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to the newly announced `bash` that will be available embedded/integrated in Windows 10, then...

Are you on the Developers Preview build 14311 or newer of Windows 10? (not available to general public, yet)? Or have you installed Ubuntu for Windows 10 from the Windows store (again, not yet available)? No to both, then you can't use bash yet.