# What is tmpgfile.sys in C:\?

Tags: windows-10-preview

Since Windows 10 Build 14316 I see a file called tmpgfile.sys:

[image]

What is this file?

Answer (score 1):

This [file seams to be the swap file/pagefile](http://www.deskmodder.de/blog/2016/04/07/ubuntu-bash-unter-windows-10-erzeugt-eine-tmpgfile-sys/) of the `Windows Subsystem for Linux`, (run the Linux [tools in the bash](https://superuser.com/a/1062261/174557)). Turning off the `Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)` removes the file.